# Jenkins as a container on AKS - Docker in Docker approach

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, containers, azure-aks

```
 We are trying to run jenkins as container in AKS Cluster. For this use case we need to implement docker in docker approach and  have an execution container(present within jenkins slave pod)  to have docker installed in it. 
    And to allow the execution environment/agent/container to run docker commands we need privileged access. 
    
    When we are trying to run docker container in privileged mode. ConstraintTemplate k8sazurev2noprivilege is restricting it  and we are getting error.


Below is the reference of the policy.

    Constraint Template k8sazurev2noprivilege: https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/KubernetesService/container-no-privilege/template.yaml
    
    
Error:
Message: admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: [azurepolicy-k8sazurev2noprivilege-*******] Privileged container is not allowed: custom, securityContext: {"privileged": true}. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=403, details=null, kind=Status, message=admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: [azurepolicy-k8sazurev2noprivilege-******] Privileged container is not allowed: custom, securityContext: {"privileged": true}, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Forbidden, status=Failure, additionalProperties={})
```

Is it necessary to run containers in privileged mode. Is there any other approach viable which doesnt require us modifying azure policy constraints.

.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Jenkins in an AKS cluster and integrating Docker, one may initially consider using Docker-in-Docker (DinD) which typically requires running containers in privileged mode. However, the Azure policy `k8sazurev2noprivilege` restricts this for security reasons. You can check whether you are running a container in privileged mode by using:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.Privileged}}' [container_id]
```

[image]

[Risks of DIND](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) from Jérôme Petazzoni’s describes the pitfalls of using Docker-in-Docker (DinD)

Here are alternative approaches that comply with this policy:

Instead of DinD, you can use the `Docker-Outside-of-Docker` (DooD) approach. This involves connecting your Jenkins container to the Docker daemon on the host. You can achieve this by mounting the Docker socket from the host:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    volumeMounts:
    - name: docker-sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
  - name: docker-sock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

[image]

```
kubectl get pods
```

[image]

Another approach is to use [Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates)

Use the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin to dynamically create agent pods for each job. This avoids the need for DinD altogether.

These alternatives provide ways to use Docker with Jenkins in AKS without requiring privileged containers, thus complying with the `k8sazurev2noprivilege` policy. Each method has its use case and benefits, and the choice depends on your specific requirements and constraints

And finally third approach is via using this tool called [kaniko](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kaniko#:%7E:text=Kaniko%20is%20a%20tool%20to,access%20like%20a%20Kubernetes%20cluster.)

*Steps*:

1. Install the [Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins.](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/)
2. [Configure](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) the plugin to connect to your AKS cluster.
3. Define a [pod template](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) for your builds.

***Reference Documents:***

[Run docker-in-docker container alongside Jenkins](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/run-docker-in-docker-container-alongside-jenkins-agent)

[Jenkins Docker in Docker](https://rokpoto.com/jenkins-docker-in-docker-agent/#use-docker-in-docker-agent)

[Jenkins Docker outside Docker](https://medium.com/@prasenjitsarkar_79320/jenkins-pod-docker-outside-of-docker-deployment-in-kubernetes-c76100173c28#:%7E:text=This%20approach%20has%20been%20called,and%20cache%20on%20the%20host.)

[DIND Pod Template](https://joostvdg.github.io/jenkins-pipeline/podtemplate-dind/)

[Risks of running DIND](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

[Jenkins from DIND to Kaniko](https://faun.pub/jenkins-on-kubernetes-moving-from-docker-in-docker-to-kaniko-b48d1a240349)

[Running containers in privileged mode](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-privileged)

Comment: thanks for sharing these details. Can you help me how using the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin , we don't require dind approach and can still have docker running in agents. Does this require docker out of docker approach. 

Do you see security concerns in Docker out of docker approach?

Comment: Using the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin allows you to run Jenkins agents as pods in a Kubernetes cluster, eliminating the need for Docker-in-Docker (DinD) for building Docker images. Instead of running Docker inside a Jenkins container. Step 1: Install and Configure Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin. Step 2: Define a Pod Template with Docker
In your Jenkins configuration, define a pod template that includes a container with Docker. This container will not run Docker itself but will instead use the Docker daemon on the Kubernetes node. Refer https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/

Comment: So you are asking to use the Docker outside docker approach. How do you consider this solution in terms of security.

Comment: I mean are you asking to implement the docker.soc approach

Comment: Yes, in my answer, I discussed the DooD approach as one of the options for running Jenkins in AKS cluster, especially in the context of avoiding DinD and privileged container issues. This approach involves connecting the Jenkins container to the Docker daemon of the host machine, typically achieved by mounting the Docker socket (/var/run/docker.sock).

Comment: Each of these approaches has its own set of trade-offs between ease of use, flexibility, and security. While the Jenkins Kubernetes plugin and Kaniko provide more secure alternatives to DinD, the Docker-Outside-of-Docker method is simpler but requires careful security considerations. Your choice depends on your specific requirements.